# MERN App getting connection error in digitalocean

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, digital-ocean

I have created my `Blog` using `MERN` application. 
So now I am hosting this in `digitalocean` server but I am getting `ECONNREFUSED` error.
I have followed most of the document in both youtube and other for hosting it.

I can see my client running on `ex: http://154.23.54.44:3000` but it is not running without `:3000` as well as neither connecting my `mlab` conection.

Any suggestion for solving this and running this aplication in real production
Many Thanks.

//server package.json

```
"main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \" npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  }
```

//server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const path = require('path');
const config =  require('config');

const app = express();

//bodyParser middleware
app.use(express.json());

//DB config
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

//connect to mongo
mongoose
.connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true})
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected...'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

//use routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));


// Serve static assets if in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // SET static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 80;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on PORT ${port}`));
```

//client (package.json)

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-less": "^3.3.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

//error on production

[image]

Comment: Several facts to note: 1. What is running on localhost:5000? 2. You haven't deployed a production build of your react app 3. Nodemon is only for dev. As an alternative, you can use `pm2` or `forever` in production.

Comment: hi @Pavindu thank you for your time. `localhost:5000` for backend. I am using command of `npm run dev` so what suppose to be I used in production?

Comment: As I see, you are running the react app from digitalocean and backend from `localhost`. Am I correct?

Comment: My backend is in `mlab` I am just connecting it with `mlab url`.

Comment: Only your mongodb database is in mlab. Your backend is the node app and it is connected to mlab with mlab url..As I can see your node server is still running on localhost...Why you are getting this error is that the react app hosted on digitalocean can't find it's backend because it's running on your pc and your pc can't be publicly accessible by digitalocean.

Comment: So how can i resolve this issue. Do you think any other files should i edit here ?
https://github.com/tanmoysarkar/MERN_blog this is my github link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212800/discussion-between-pavindu-and-tanmoy-sarkar).